# How to rotate all applications that use camera in android?

Tags: android, camera, rotation, orientation, preview

There are some apps for screen rotation in the Play Store, such as:

- Rotation - Orientation Manager;
- Ultimate Rotation Control;
- Rotation Control;
- And others.

The purpose of these apps is to change the orientation of the phone screen for all applications in the device, using one of the following orientational attributes:

["Landscape" | "Portrait" | "ReverseLandscape" | "ReversePortrait" | "SensorLandscape" | "SensorPortrait" | "UserLandscape" | "UserPortrait" |
"Sensor" | "FullSensor" | "Nosensor" | "User" | "FullUser" | "Locked"](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html)

But for applications that use the camera, none of these rotational apps completely works, because the preview of the camera is not rotated.
Examples: the native camera application, Google Goggles or other applications using camera are not rotated completely, only the components overlayed on the screen are rotated.

**QUESTION: How do I create an app to rotate all applications, based on the principle of the rotational apps in the Play Store, but such that in applications that use camera, the preview's orientation is also rotated?**

PS: For a possible solution's test, I tried to use Xposed framework, doing a setRequestedOrientation in all Activities at *onResume* method, but it didn't work.

Comment: Some scenarios can be handled, but probably not "all". How much are you willing to invest in this app?

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for your answer. In fact, I need only to perform some tests. I have no money for investment, only time, but if I can get an idea of where to go to accomplish such a thing, would be interesting. May be if it only work for some application, it's good for me. I thought the possibility to modify the gravity sensor and accelerometer (invert them), but it didn't work properly.

Comment: I would suggest to start small: take an open-source camera app that only supports Landscape, and see what must be done (in Java) to fully support Portrait mode. The next challenge is to support auto-rotate. When you are done, try to do the same to some closed-source 3ᴿᴰ party app (un-dex it to smali, and modify as needed).

Comment: Thank you Alex. I'll try it,